# Linux,c++, negative exit codes, clarifiction?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, return, zsh

In Linux, c++ can we return exit codes? i.e is this code valid:

```
int main()
{
  return -1;
}
```

The reason I am asking if this code is compiled and executed from bash/zsh, the return value would be 255, I thin this due to the fact that its using an 8 bit return code, and that implies that return codes are only allowed to be between positive.

Is this correct?

Comment: Cross duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/why-do-i-get-error-255-when-returning-1

Comment: Yes, shell is only working with 0 - 255 as a return code value.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant system call is `_exit()`, and [POSIX itself specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html) that only the bottom 8 bits of the status given to `_exit()` are normally usable:

> `_exit(status)`
>   The value of status may be `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, or any other value, though only the least significant 8 bits (that is, `status & 0377`) shall be available from `wait()` and `waitpid()`;

Though it goes on to say that "the full value shall be available from `waitid()`", but on Linux, I seem to still get just the low eight bits.

Answer (score 0):

NO, exit code passed to `exit(2)` is merged with data for cases in which your program is interrupted by means of a signal sent to it.  `exit(2)` return code is *only* the least signifiant byte of the code returned by `wait(2)`.  See pages for `wait(2)` and `exit(2)` for an explanation of how the return code is formed.