# valgrind --error-exitcode , negative values

Tags: bash, valgrind

I'm trying to set a **custom error code** if `valgrind` reports an error(building a test script), but it doesn't seem to work as expected when setting a negative value, this how I run `valgrind`:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=-1 -q ./leaks
```

This however, returns `0` (which is the return value of `leaks`), instead of `-1`.

```
echo $?
0
```

If a positive value is set, it works as expected:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 -q ./leaks

echo $?
1
```

The [Valgrind manual](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html), specifies:

> `--error-exitcode=<number> [default: 0]`
>
> Specifies an alternative exit code to return if Valgrind reported any errors in the run. When set to the default value (zero), the
> return value from Valgrind will always be the return value of the
> process being simulated. When set to **a nonzero value**, that value is
> returned instead, if Valgrind detects any errors. This is useful for
> using Valgrind as part of an automated test suite, since it makes it
> easy to detect test cases for which Valgrind has reported errors, just
> by inspecting return codes.

Anybody knows why this behavior occurs?

**Using Valgrind-3.10.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual is inaccurate, Valgrind can't return a negative value, it is in [Valgrind's source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=valgrind.git;a=blob_plain;f=coregrind/m_main.c;hb=HEAD). It assigns the option's value to `clo_eror_exitcode`:

```c
else if VG_INT_CLO (arg, "--error-exitcode", VG_(clo_error_exitcode)) {}
```

and then checks if it is positive, otherwise it ignores the option.

```c
if (VG_(clo_error_exitcode) > 0
    && VG_(get_n_errs_found)() > 0) {
   VG_(client_exit)( VG_(clo_error_exitcode) );
} else {
   /* otherwise, return the client's exit code, in the normal
      way. */
   VG_(client_exit)( VG_(threads)[tid].os_state.exitcode );
}
```

Even if it could, it would not be useful as per [Linux, negative exit codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44231090)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the additional info!