# can't return negative values

Tags: c, ubuntu

i am working on a C homework my teacher gave me, using it on a ubuntu environment with GCC.
We have to recreate a kind of "round" from the "math.h" header, but without using any function nor header, and by not by checking on the working of this function. I created a code that allowed me to do it for positive values, and it works just fine. I used the same logic for the negative values, but when i ask my main to return a negative value, it always return me a "251", which is not the value i'm asking for. Here is my code :

**my_round.c**

```
int my_round(float n)
{
    if (n<0)
    {
        float res = n-0.5;
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        float res = n+0.5;
        return res;
    }
}
```

**main_round.c**

```
int my_round(float n);

int main(void)
{
    return my_round(-5.2);
}
```

Then i use gcc this way :

```
gcc main_round.c my_round.c -o round.out
```

I then execute **./round.out**, which returns me when "**251**" i ask for "**echo $?**".
But it does work correctly with the positive values, i tested all values trhrough (like 1.1; 1.2; etc... all the way to 1.9).
I'd really apreciate if anyone would lend a hand to me please, and thank you!
Bloster

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227722/linux-c-negative-exit-codes-clarifiction

Comment: I am rather sure that you are not supposed to return the result as exit code of your program but just to print it on `stdout`. The exit code should reflect the success of your program, not some result of math function.

Comment: Does your function `my_round` work when you print the result with `printf` instead of attempting to read the return value of `main` in an external program?

Comment: Our teacher told us to exit it this way, as we did not see the pointers ATM, but it works if i try to use put, so the problem resolves around the return, i must exit it by the return, we have already done that on our previous exercices...

Comment: @John3136 thanks for the link, but it seems to be more about c++ and linux outputs rather than c and return, i'll still read this more carefully rn

Comment: It's the same in C and C++. The issue is not with the language but with what the OS allows as an exit value.

Comment: In ubuntu, you can return 0-255. Everything else will be truncated/converted to fit into 0-255. See also [Exit Codes With Special Meanings](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) to be able to communicate with other programs in a meaningful way.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah thx, i've seen this in the post linked earlier by john, but i need to find a way to go around this restriction, as we have to "return the rounded value of the float parameter"...

Comment: Then, if your function is only ever going to return something in the range -128 to 127, I suggest wrapping the program in a shell script that converts 0 to 255 into -128 to 127.

Comment: well yes, but actually no, the script won't be transfered to my teacher, so the exercise would be false...

Comment: I assume you've taken the teacher's instructions too literally. Returning this from a program as an exit code is bonkers..

Comment: well the order from our teacher is the following : Your function should return the rounded value of the float parameter. It must work with negatives values too.

Comment: If you only provide the function to your teacher, then why do you think the teacher won't test it with a `main` function that simply prints the result?

Comment: I agree with @interjay "your function" is most probably not supposed to be `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is about return code
Return code is unsigned between 0 and 255

Print value is `-5` the return value is `251`
So your code is good the way you test it is not good

This code is displaying:

```
-5
251
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int my_round(float n)
{
    if (n<0)
    {
        float res = n-0.5;
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        float res = n+0.5;
        return res;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int res = my_round(-5.2);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    printf("%u\n", ((unsigned int)res)&0Xff);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Well, i guess you pointed out an interesting idea, but i'll have to excuse myself here, i ommited a detail. we are asked to use no functions nor headers... so stdio.h and stdlib.h can't be in our code, or it would appear as an error for our teacher... and we won't be the one giving our teacher the "main.c" part, we can only use it on our side to test our values. he will create it on his behalf, with only one command : return my_round(value);

Comment: @Bloster you should distinguis 2 things: 1) implementing the function without any standard header and library function. 2) testing the beast. While your restriction is valid for 1) it does not make much sense for 2). For testing you can normally throw anything you have at the target to make it fail. This means: no headers in `my_round.c` but no limitations for `main_round.c`.

Comment: @Gerhardh indeed i could add these 2 libraries in my main_round.c, but it wouldn't affect my problem here, as my teacher is the one creating this main_round.c part, and he said he wanted it into a return, not in a printf, nor a puts or whatever, so first thanks for that clarification, but this can't be the answer as he will only be putting what i put in my main_round.c as a way to test our program T-T

Comment: Ok, I add another printf to show you that the code is good.
What test you should implement ? The test part is not clear